# Upgrading Python3 on Ubuntu/Vagrant

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, package, apt

How do I upgrade my python3 installation on Ubuntu? In particular, from 3.5.2 --> 3.6.x

Here's the basic attempt, though I have also tried `remove` and `purge` commands with no apparent effect.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-130-generic x86_64)
$ ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2 
$ sudo apt-get install python3 3.6 --reinstall
... [no errors, lots of output]
$ ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

at this point I'd expected to see Python 3.6.x as the version. I don't see any new entries in `/usr/bin`

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant$ ll /usr/bin | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         26 May 18  2016 dh_pypy -> ../share/dh-python/dh_pypy*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root       1056 Nov 24  2017 dh_python2*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         29 May 18  2016 dh_python3 -> ../share/dh-python/dh_python3*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         23 Dec  4  2017 pdb2.7 -> ../lib/python2.7/pdb.py*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         23 Nov 28  2017 pdb3.5 -> ../lib/python3.5/pdb.py*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         31 Mar 23  2016 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         26 May 18  2016 pybuild -> ../share/dh-python/pybuild*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          9 Nov 24  2017 python -> python2.7*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          9 Nov 24  2017 python2 -> python2.7*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    3492656 Dec  4  2017 python2.7*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root          9 Mar 23  2016 python3 -> python3.5*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4464400 Nov 28  2017 python3.5*
-rwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4464400 Nov 28  2017 python3.5m*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         10 Mar 23  2016 python3m -> python3.5m*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root         29 Nov 24  2017 pyversions -> ../share/python/pyversions.py*
```

there's no immediate evidence that anything new was installed

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:/vagrant$ py3versions -i
python3.5
```

All I want is to have python3 >= 3.6 installed on this virtual machine. I don't *at all* care about previous installations, python2, virtualenvs, or any of the general server-health things, as this is a totally isolated development box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ubuntu 16.04, you can use [Felix Krull's deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa:)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Alternatively, you can use [J Fernyhough's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6:)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

If you want to Compile and install python 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
tar xvf Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.0/
./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: ok, but what's wrong with the existing repositories? I'm not getting any indication that there is any problem with the packages themselves, but I'm not getting the results I'm expecting, either

Comment: In ubuntu 16.04 python3 comes as default version 3.5.  
> 3.5 versions are not available via existing repositories because of this reason.
from 16.10 python3 comes as the default version of 3.6.

you can also Install the necessary dependencies, download the python 3.6 source code, and build the environment and install.

I have updated the answer. please accept it if it solves your problem.